# Dynamic where statement efectively

Tags: php, mysql

So I was wondering what the most efficient way to search a database using WHERE.

If I have var such as

```
$conditions = "1,3,4,9"
```

With each of these ints referencing a primary id of a table. So what is the best way to select these rows from mysql.

```
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($conditions); $i++)
{
  if($conditions[$i] == ',')
   continue;
  $conn->prepare('select * FROM table WHERE id= $i');
}
```

I was thinking about doing something above however, I am sure there would be more efficient ways then this.

Ps. I know the code above won't work and i wrong it was just an example I wrote up then.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: in this case use find_in_set

Comment: Or you can use `IN` query

Comment: Right, if you have array than use IN else use find_in_set for comma separated string

Comment: Explode the `$conditions` then build an `in` group. Proper way with prepared statement: https://3v4l.org/06uiU

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is find_in_set:

```
select * from ... where find_in_set($conditions, id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string into array:

```
$conditions = explode(",","1,3,4,9");
foreach($conditions as $id){
  $conn->prepare('select * FROM table WHERE id= $id');
}
```